# rsync following symlink and deleting only the symlink upon completion

Tags: automation, rsync, symbolic-link

## expected scenario

Essentially I want to use rsync as a tool to do automatic queued downloading.

Say we have the following directory structure on remote.

```
to_be_downloaded
├── symlink1
└── symlink2
```

I want to use rsync to download the actual file referred to by the symlink and delete the symlink if the download is successful.

Then I make a crontab to let rsync to do that say every hour. In that way, when I want local to download some file from remote, I just put a symlink in the folder `to_be_downloaded`, and the deletion ensures that each file will be downloaded only once.

## question

How to make rsync follow symlink and delete only the symlink not the actual file upon completion? Other workarounds not using rsync achieving the same effect are also welcomed.